# Gulp merge json files from different folders while keeping folder structure

Tags: json, merge, gulp

I would like to merge multiple .json files from different folders while keeping the general folder structure.

Input

```
/lang/module1/file1.json
/lang/module1/file2.json
/lang/module2/file1.json
/lang/module2/subModule1/file1.json

/lang_additional/module1/file1.json
/lang_additional/module1/file2.json
/lang_additional/module2/file1.json
/lang_additional/module2/subModule1/file1.json
```

Expected Output

```
/dist/lang/module1/file1.json                (both file1.json's merged)
/dist/lang/module1/file2.json                (both file2.json's merged)
/dist/lang/module2/file1.json                (both file1.json's merged)
/dist/lang/module2/subModule1/file1.json     (both file1.json's merged)
```

Is it possible to achieve this with gulp?  There may be multiple folders and subfolders.  I wish to designate which parent folder has precedence in the merge conflict resolution.

Answer (score 1):

This works for your example input **and** I believe any number of subfolders in each folder.  If there is a matching file in another directory it is added to a streams array that will then be used to start the necessary number of gulp streams to send to 'gulp-merge-json' and your 'dist' output with the folder structure retained.

Use with "gulp mergeJSON"

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var merge = require('gulp-merge-json');

const files = [];
const parentFolders = [];
let   streams = [];
const baseNames = [];

//    note that the way 'gulp-merge-json' works is the last file having the same key as an earlier file 'wins' on the merge
//    so whichever directory is listed last in the folders array will have PRECEDENCE
//   'gulp-merge-json' will also take an 'edit' function option

// [  in the comments you said you wanted the 'lang' folder structure preserved in './dist'
//     but with 'lang_additional' precedence  ]

//  By the way, this works with more than two directories or it can work with
// folders of different levels such as:
//         const folders = ['lang', 'lang_additional/module1/subModule2'];
// only merging those files with the same directory structure starting at the deepest
// levels only. So in the above example, only within subModule2 and below.

const folders = ['lang', 'lang_additional'];

gulp.task('mergeJSON', function () {

  getFiles(folders);
  makeStreams();

    // streams[1] =   lang\module1\file2.json,   lang_additional\module1\file2.json

  // spin up multiple "streams", not really a stream yet until gulp.src creates one
  streams.forEach(function (stream) {

    //  get the fileName from one of the stream files, they all end with the same file
    let fileName = path.basename(stream[stream.length - 1]);

    //  get the directories of one of the streams, again all files within a stream have the same directories
    let dirName = path.dirname(stream[stream.length - 1]);
    // strip off the first directory, leaving all subdirectories
    dirName = dirName.substr(dirName.indexOf(path.sep));

    return gulp.src(stream)
      .pipe(merge({ fileName: fileName }))

      // since the question wanted a dist/lang/subfolders hierarchy
      .pipe(gulp.dest(path.join('./dist', 'lang', dirName)));
  });
});

// getFiles is recursive, if a "file" retrieved by fs.readdirSync is a directory

function getFiles(folders) {

  let possibleDirectory;

  folders.forEach(function (folder, index) {

    // read the file list from each directory
    let tempFiles = fs.readdirSync('./' + folder);

    tempFiles.forEach(function (fileOrDirectory) {

      possibleDirectory = path.join(folder, fileOrDirectory);
      if (fs.lstatSync(possibleDirectory).isDirectory())  {
        getFiles([possibleDirectory]);
      }
      else {

        // files[] will include all files found under the folders array
        files.push(path.join(folder, fileOrDirectory));

        if (baseNames.indexOf(fileOrDirectory) === -1) {

          // if that file name element doesn't already exist in baseName array
          // an array of just the basenames of true files
          baseNames.push(fileOrDirectory);
        }
      }
    });
  });
}

function makeStreams() {

  // for each file, find and save its parent directories without the folders[] "root" directories
  files.forEach(function (file) {

    let thisParentFolders = path.dirname(file).substr(file.indexOf(path.sep));

    if (parentFolders.indexOf(thisParentFolders) === -1) {

      // if that parentfolder  doesn't already exist in baseName array
      parentFolders.push(thisParentFolders);
    }
  });

  // now loop through all unique directories looking for those files with each parentFolder with baseName attached
  parentFolders.forEach(function (folder) {

    let foldersFile = folder.substr(folder.indexOf(path.sep));

    baseNames.forEach(function (baseName) {

      streams.push(files.filter(function (file) {
         return file.endsWith(path.join(foldersFile, baseName));
      }));
    });
  });

  //    Here: remove any "streams" (array sub-elements) that have only one file in them, length == 1
  //    But for now this filter is necessary due to a undefined entry in .
  streams = streams.filter( stream => stream.length >= 1);

  streams.forEach( (stream, index) => console.log("streams[" + index + "] = " + stream));
}
```

Comment: It is not working for more than two directories right now.  I'll have a look at that later.

Comment: I simplified the code.  It is now working for any number of directories.

Comment: This already helped a bit, however i would need this solution recursively for all subfolders too, as there isn't only a module 1 folder but also module 2-x, which themselves could have submodules. And that's the point where i am stuck right now.

    /lang/module1/file1.json
    /lang/module2/file1.json
    /lang/module3/submodule1/file.json
    /lang_additional/module1/file1.json
    /lang_additional/module2/file1.json
    /lang_additional/module3/submodule1/file.json

Comment: So, do you wish to merge all file1.json's together no matter where they are or how deep?  It shouldn't be too hard to modify the code with this new information.  And everything is in the parent directory to lang, lang_additional, etc.?

Comment: No i don't want to merge all file1.json into one. In short i would like to copy the lang folder 1:1 while keeping all subfolders, then i would like to merge all json files which exists in lang_alternative into this folder structure.

Comment: So lang_additional/module2/submodule3/file5.json would be merged into lang/module2/submodule3/file5.json?  Merge the same filenames but only in the same module/submodule structure?  Not that it matters, but is there only "lang" and "lang_additional" parent folders you are interested in?  Or is there some parent directory to them that should be the starting point?

Comment: Thats exactly what i want to archive. And yes there is only land and lang_additional.

Comment: And do you care about the precedence order?  If two file1.json's have the same key, the last encountered file's value will be used for the merged file.  That is why I put the lang directory last in my original code above.  Perhaps you never have the same keys in different file1.json's?

Comment: Its fine if the value from the lang_alternatives file will be used

Comment: @r3vile Another edit to the code.  I believe it works as you intend.  The second directory, 'lang_additional',  gets merge precedence (listed last) but the 'lang' folder structure is used.  LMK.